# How to use React refs inside FluentUI DetailsList onRender function

Tags: office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui

I need to use a ref inside the `onRender` function of a FluentUI DetailsList column. But If I try to use a string ref: e.g: `ref={"myref"}` React complains that `react-dom.development.js:13381 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Function components cannot have string refs. We recommend using useRef() instead. Learn more about using refs safely here:....`. And if I try to use useRef I get an error that the onRender function is not a functional component. How can I use refs (multiple) in the FluentUI DetailsList onRender function?

Comment: Mind adding a bit more context on the exact thing you're hoping to do with the ref? Do you want a ref to an entire column? A ref for each cell in a particular column?

Comment: I want a ref to a a component inside the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to override the rendering of rows/columns within DetailsList.

To define new content for a column, the easiest way is to define an `onRender` value in the column definition. For instance, in this snippet `column3` has a function called every time it renders cells in that column.

```js
const _columns = [
      { key: 'column1', name: 'Name', fieldName: 'name', minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 200, isResizable: true },
      { key: 'column2', name: 'Value', fieldName: 'value', minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 200, isResizable: true },
      { key: 'column3', name: 'Custom value with ref', fieldName: 'value', minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 200, onRender: renderColumn3 },
    ];
```

The `onRender` callback is called with the original item, the index in the list, and the column definition. From there it's trivial to return a react component, which can use any hooks it needs (such as `useRef`).

This example renders a very simple component that uses refs:

```tsx
const MyControlForColumn3 = props => {
  const myRef = React.useRef();

  return <div ref={myRef}><button onClick={() => console.log(myRef.current)}>Print ref.current to console</button>{props.children}</div>;
}

const renderColumn3 = (item: any, itemIndex: any, columnDefinition: any) => {
  return <MyControlForColumn3>Item #{itemIndex}</MyControlForColumn3>
}
```

([Full working example on codepen](https://codepen.io/jdh-msft/pen/mdVPwpw?editors=0010))